# How to move to a certain view using ViewFlipper?

Tags: android

I would like to switch to certain views in a ViewFlipper. Currently, I have 6 children inside the ViewFlipper. And I am having some buttons for navigation. It is very much similar to "News and weather" application.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Call `setDisplayedChild()`, passing the `0`-based index of the child `View` you want to display.

Answer (score 25):

See this simple complete example of [android.widget.ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). With it you can create different layout from xml and then switch among them with simple method like this:

```
   ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.myViewFlipper);

   // you can switch between next and previous layout and display it
   viewFlipper.showNext();
   viewFlipper.showPrevious();

  // or you can switch selecting the layout that you want to display
  viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
  viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(viewFlipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.secondLayout)
```

Xml example with tree layouts:

```
     <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/myViewFlipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
               [...]
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
               [...]
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thirdLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
              [...]
            </LinearLayout>
      </ViewFlipper>
```